# Why can't you call a variable that has been initialised in a loop and declared beforehand?

Tags: java, loops, variables, initialization

i.e. with the variables "location" and longitude below, surely they are initialised within the while loops?

```
String calledAddress = intent.getStringExtra("address");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("latitude=(.*?),hasLongitude");
Matcher m = p.matcher(calledAddress);
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
while (m.find()){
    latitude = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
}

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("longitude=(.*?),phone");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(calledAddress);

while (m1.find()){
    longitude = Double.parseDouble(m1.group(1));
}

LatLng clickedLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude); // ERROR HERE "latitude/longtitude may not have been initialised"
```

Comment: IMHO you should use double primitives, instead of Double wrapper type, the use of the wrapper is unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexanderDaum Even you change them to primitives, you see the compiler error.

Comment: @ANS, I have not said, that it will remove the error, there are already multiple answers saying why the error is there and how to fix it, I just wanted to point out, that it would be better to use primitives instead of wrappers if not necessary

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not accessibility. Problem is with the chances of local variables that may not get initialised before they got used.

All the local variables must be initialised before they use and in your case there might be a chance that the while loop may not go inside. Hence it should have a default value.

In your case , you may initialise them with null or zero.

```
 Double latitude =0;
 Double longitude =0;
```

Comment: This might cause another problem down the line if `LatLng` is initialised with 0 values which is something OP might not want.

Comment: @DarshanMehta That is clearly functional, as we have no clue about the scope the entire project :)

Answer (score 2):

Because they may not initialized. Both find could return false.

Comment: Yes i see now. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. If either of `m.find()` and `m1.find()` returns false, corresponding variable won't be `initialised`. And Java does not allow you to access the variable's `value` unless it's initialised, hence the error.

If you don't want your code to proceed further if these are not `initialised` then you can assign `null` values and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if they are still `null`, e.g.:

```
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
while (m.find()){

    latitude = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));

}

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("longitude=(.*?),phone");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(calledAddress);

while (m1.find()){

     longitude = Double.parseDouble(m1.group(1));

}
if(null == latitude || null == longitude){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Pattern. Both longitude and latitude must be present.");
}
```

Comment: @Adam J an additional way to thank answers that address your need is upvoting them :)

Answer (score 1):

`latitude` and `longitude` local variable cannot be considered as initialized by the compiler as they depend on the conditional statements in the loops : `while (m.find()){` and `while (m1.find()){`.

How to be sure that these conditions be true ?

In fact, assigning them to `0` or `null` in their declaration will not necessarily solve your problem :

```
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
```

because you would provide to  `new LatLng(latitude,longitude)` probably incorrect values.

`LatLng clickedLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);`  should be probably executed only if `latitude` and `longitude` were found in the loop.

You should probably chain this processing : if you find both latitude and longitude values, you create a `LatLng` instance with these parameters.
Otherwise you should handle this missing data situation.

For example :

```
 Double latitude = null;
 Double longitude = null;

 while (m.find()){    
       latitude = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));    
 }

 Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("longitude=(.*?),phone");
 Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(calledAddress);

 while (m1.find()){    
      longitude = Double.parseDouble(m1.group(1));    
 }

 // successful case
 if (latitude != null && longitude != null){
      LatLng clickedLocation = new LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
        ...
 }
 // unsuccessful case
 else{
      ...   
 }
```